# Class aws does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I have followed following steps

1. "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0" and updated composer
2. Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider::class in providers
3. 'AWS' => Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade::class, in Aliases
4. php artisan vendor:publish
5. added aws.php in confg

Still i get error that class aws not found

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this package:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
```